# Sharing views between 2 devise models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 devise users, *admin* and *user*, who can say, *edit* a page.

For *admin*, we have a edit_admin_page route
For *user*, we have a edit_user_page route

The only difference between the 2 views will be the edit page url.

I want to write only 1 view for both users for which the edit page url changes based on the devise user.

Comment: creating,rendering a partial would do i guess.

Comment: if user_signed_in? 
render 'user_button' 
elsif admin_signed_in? 
render 'admin_button'

Is this what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

For now I did the following,

After I authenticate my devise object (admin/user), I set @current_devise_scope as either 'admin' or 'user' and then in shared view, I added

```
send("edit_#{@current_devise_scope}s_path_path", @page.id)
```

This works for all the shared views now.

I couldn't find a way to access devise's current_devise_scope if there is any.